# A word for a common statement, "I don't want to do it."

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not sure if this is a platitude, an adage, or what, but I'm looking for an accurate word for common phrases that aren't necessarily a proverb, like, "I don't want to do it."

Comment: Be merciful and give a context.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with declarative sentence or declarative statement.

As per the Cambridge Dictionary:

a sentence that makes a statement or states a fact.

(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/declarative-sentence)